# Document describing Lua 5.2 implementation?

Tags: lua

Lua.org has a [very nice document](http://www.lua.org/doc/jucs05.pdf) which describes implementation strategies and novelties of Lua 5.0.

In Lua 5.2 we can add a serious incremental garbage collector and a goto statement to the Lua 5.0 feature list. I would really like to read about how they implemented them (without digging too much in the source).

So, is there a document like the one for 5.0 available for 5.2 somewhere?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a presentation about [Lua 5.2 novelties](http://www.inf.puc-rio.br/~roberto/talks/novelties-5.2.pdf) by Roberto Ierusalimschy. Although it does not give details about garbage collection, there is a slide describing the implementation of `goto` (slide 17).

If you need more details, I guess you will need to take a look at the source (it's actually pretty readable).

Answer (score 3):

Lua 5.1 introduced incremental garbage collection.

Lua 5.2 introduced generational garbage collection as an experimental feature.

But, no, there is no document on this implementation.